# How to override total in gravity forms

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

I want to display and checkout my custom price in gravity forms,

i already try

```
gform.addFilter( 'gform_product_total', function(total, formId){
// do something with the total
return total;
} );
```

This Hook override total but it's just display new total but cant get this new total in checkout, so i want to change this total with my custom price and when user do checkout they pay new custom price.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to filter the total via the PHP [gform_product_info](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_product_info/) filter as well.

Comment: You need to tell the solution here instead of commenting!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Is there any examples of this? I'm having the same issue, can update the total field but in the cart (WooCommerce) its the standard price. Have tested the gform_product_info and it updates all my products in the cart, how do I use it the way you mention?

Comment: This example from the documentation shows how to modify the name of the product. Use the "price" index instead of the "name" to modify the price.

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_product_info/#3-modify-product-name